# Error al obtener SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android

Estoy intentado crear una clase para obtener los datos predefinidos, pero cuando llamo el metodo `Load()` se detiene la app.
¿Me podrian ayudar? Gracias

```
package com.example.nano.prueba.login.loginprueba;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;


/**
 * Created by admin on 02/04/2016.
 */
public class LoadPreferencias extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String User;
    private String Pass;

    public void Load(){

        SharedPreferences Preferencias = getSharedPreferences("DatosUser", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        User =(Preferencias.getString("User",""));
        Pass = (Preferencias.getString("Pass", ""));

    }

    public String GetUser()
    {
        Load();
        return User;
    }
    public String GetPass()
    {
        return Pass;
    }



}
```

agrego codigo de error

> 04-03 09:55:44.445 31786-31786/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   main
>                                                      Process: com.example.nano.prueba.login.loginprueba, PID: 31786
>                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.nano.prueba.login.loginprueba/com.example.nano.prueba.login.loginprueba.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.content.SharedPreferences
>   android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2658)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2723)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
>                                                       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.content.SharedPreferences
>   android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                          at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:184)
>                                                          at com.example.nano.prueba.login.loginprueba.LoadPref.Load(LoadPref.java:16)
>                                                          at com.example.nano.prueba.login.loginprueba.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41)
>                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6221)
>                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2611)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2723) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422) 
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832) 
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)

Comment: Hola Alejandro,  puedes depurar la aplicación y decirnos en que línea se cae y cual es el mensaje de error obtenido?

Comment: Como comenta Carlos siempre es importante mencionar cual es el error, en el caso de Android que mensaje de error se despliega en el LogCat cuando tienes el error!

Comment: hola, @Elenasys, agrego codigo de error.

Comment: eso es perfecto, ahora reviso.

Comment: El problema es que estas llamando tus métodos desde MainActivity que es otra clase y el contexto en LoadPreferencias no es el mismo, te sugiero envies el contexto de la aplicación desde MainActivity, ve mi respuesta, ahora verifico mi código ya que estoy escribiendo desde un móvil =P.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De acuerdo a tu mensaje de error:

> android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.nano.prueba.login.loginprueba/com.example.nano.prueba.login.loginprueba.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences

estas llamando el método Load()  desde   MainActivity, el método Load() necesita recibir el Contexto, por eso el error!, modifica tu método para que lo reciba:

```
   public void Load(Context context){

    SharedPreferences Preferencias = context.getSharedPreferences("DatosUser", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    User =(Preferencias.getString("User",""));
    Pass = (Preferencias.getString("Pass", ""));

}
```

Aunque un diseño mejor sería crear 2 métodos que llames cuando requieras los valores de User o Pass, tu clase `LoadPreferencias` no necesita extender de  `AppCompatActivity`, y aquí mismo puedes agregar los métodos para guardar los valores, `setUser()` y `setPass()` :

```
public class LoadPreferencias {

    public static String GetUser(Context context)
    {
     SharedPreferences Preferencias = context.getSharedPreferences("DatosUser", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String   User =Preferencias.getString("User","");
        return User;
    }


    public static String GetPass(Context context)
    {
      SharedPreferences Preferencias = context.getSharedPreferences("DatosUser", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String   Pass =Preferencias.getString("Pass","");
        return Pass;
    }  
}
```

Desde `MainActivity` elecutarías los métodos de esta forma:

```
String usuario = LoadPreferencias.GetUser(getApplicationContext());
String password = LoadPreferencias.GetPass(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: Tal cual esa es la respuesta correcta.! eres la mejor ! xD... thanks so much. @Elenasys

Comment: Que bien que solucionaste tu problema, siempre trata de agregar tus mensajes de LogCat para que te podamos ayudar ! saludos!